# Button to reach a list of useful links

Tags: feature-request

I recently tried to help on tex.stackexchange and what stroke me was the great amount of newcomers, unfortunately lacking some useful habits such as posting a MWE.

Consequently, a lot of comments on questions are about posting a MWE or adding a code snippet ...
Fortunately several posts exist on how to write a correct question / MWE but are sometimes not well-known to average-experienced tex users willing to help (such as myself).

Therefore, don't you think it would be nice to have a short list of links including [this one](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1) for instance, just when writing a comment to a question, in order to have sort of a constant process to help newcomers ?

It may not be appropriate or even useful, but anyway I'd like to exchange opinion on this matter.

Comment: Perhaps not the same what you request, but here's a question with text blocks to provide for comments:  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, this is exactly the type of information I am looking for. Actually, I just put you link in my bookmark list. My point is that it would be nice to see this type of links somewhere in the page like the "Linked" of "Related" lists

Comment: @BambOo If these links would appear by default, they would also appear in well-written questions. Do you really want this? Notice that [Peter Grill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill)'s profile also has a number of useful text fragments.

Comment: @marmot, this is obviously the main drawback. As I said in my question, what I propose may not be appropriate, let's hope the idea is useful ! I know it's not a proper rule, but it could automatically appear, if there is no `\documentclass ... \begin{document} ... \end{document}` in a single code snippet in the question for example. This could work for missing MWEs but could be complex to set up for every case.

Comment: But not every question needs an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6813/35864. I prefer the manual approach of reading the question and then deciding whether I need an MWE to understand it or not.

Comment: @moewe, the post you refered to is closely related indeed. I understand this could be annoying for experienced users. Maybe some setting in the preferences could allow to avoid unnecesary information to appear ? Some "show helpful links" checkbox ?

Comment: for the more specific case of trying to find a duplicate or related question, this list exists: [Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419). not quite the same level, but useful for the next step after question is clear.

Comment: It's funny because now I see every (useful !) link posted in the "Linked" pane, just what i needed :)

Comment: @BambOo: Because we added links in the comments

Comment: see https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, yes I guessed so ;)

Comment: @samcarter, so it seems I am not the only one asking for such a feature ...

Comment: @BambOo No, you are not :) I myself use http://aecreations.sourceforge.net/clippings/

Comment: About every 6 months this discussion pops up.